# How to publish an app with Air 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air

I have overlaid Air 3.0 over the flex sdk. I have targeted swf version 13 and included 3.0 in the header of my xml file, is there anything else i need to do to get my app published with air 3.0.

Also is there a way to check what version of air the app has been published with once it has been published?

I am using flash builder 4.5 and osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the AIR version at runtime using `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion`

**Edit:**

Also remember that there are different SDKs for Windows and for OSX. The Windows SDK does not work on OSX and vice-versa. Attempting to do so results in a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

OS X doesn't really matter.

Your application descriptor has changed in format since AIR2.0 The easiest way to check this is create a new AIR 3 project and check the app descriptor xml for that application, and compare it to yours. You will easily find out the differences.

The AIR runtime version (as lukevanin said) can be read from

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion
```

Then you can publish in the same way as before (export release build -> select certificates, etc)